# Spark Dataframe to JSON error

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried the `df.write.mode("append").json(targetPath)`method for writing multiple rows into a JSON file. Unfortunately, the output always seem to be missing commas between objects. For example, I am getting the following output

```
{"time_stamp":"2016-12-08 01:45:00","Temperature":0.8,"Energy":111111.5,"Net_Energy":1111.3}
{"time_stamp":"2016-12-08 02:00:00","Temperature":21.9,"Energy":222222.5,"Net_Energy":222.0}
```

While I was expecting

```
{"time_stamp":"2016-12-08 01:45:00","Temperature":0.8,"Energy":111111.5,"Net_Energy":1111.3},
{"time_stamp":"2016-12-08 02:00:00","Temperature":21.9,"Energy":222222.5,"Net_Energy":222.0}
```

As you can see that there is no comma between two objects in the output.
Am I missing anything?

Also, is there a method to save each row in a separate JSON file without going to through the expensive filter() method?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding your first question, the output you are getting is the correct format. Multiplie documents in a json file are not separated by comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma separator between JSON objects with json.dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766840/comma-separator-between-json-objects-with-json-dump)