# pandas dictionary to json append to file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to write dictionaries with 3 items each into a json file which i'll ultimately be using with pandas.

Each dictionary looks something like this:

```
xyz_dictionary = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3}
```

I am doing the following to make it into a string and then add it to a `.json` file:

```
with open('jsonfile.json', 'a') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json.dumps(xyz_dictionary, indent=4))
```

I'm in a situation where new 'xyz' dictionaries are constantly being created so I have to turn each one into a json format and then append it to the json file. The problem is that after I'm done my json file ends up looking like this:

```
 {
    "x": -0.03564453125,
    "y": -0.00830078125,
    "z": 1.0244140625
}{
    "x": -0.0361328125,
    "y": -0.0087890625,
    "z": 1.0244140625
}{
    "x": -0.0390625,
    "y": -0.0087890625,
    "z": 1.025390625
}{
    "x": -0.03662109375,
    "y": -0.0087890625,
    "z": 1.0263671875
}
```

in which the json objects aren't comma separated. When i try to load this with pandas i get a `trailing Data` ValueError

as u can see it's not a big array with a bunch of json objects inside of it, its just a bunch of non-comma separated json objects

to sum up, the question is 'how do i create comma separated json objects and write them to a `.json` file that is a compilation of them all?'

thank u

Comment: You are opening the json file in append mode. Looks like you're just appending a new dict every time. Please show us more of the code pertaining to how you are saving the dicts and how you're loading into pandas

Comment: My assumption is you're trying to save a list of dicts into the file but I could be wrong

Comment: A bunch of json objects separated by commas is not a valid json *either*.

Comment: I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766840/comma-separator-between-json-objects-with-json-dump)

Comment: @Jaba that is correct, i'm trying to save a a list of dicts. each dict is being generated by an accelerometor sensor so, as i said, a new dict is being created every ~1 sec. I'm simply getting back a 3-item dictionary every time, so I guess I need to create an emtpy list and append to it whenever a new dict is created and then save that to a json file somehow? thank u

Comment: @anky_91 this is very helpful, thank u

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** I would suggest you create an array of json objects

```
import json

{ 'xyz_data': 
[{
    "x": -0.03564453125,
    "y": -0.00830078125,
    "z": 1.0244140625
},
{
    "x": -0.03564453125,
    "y": -0.00830078125,
    "z": 1.0244140625
}, ...
]}
```

Use append to add to the dic

```
outfile = "Pathforfile.csv"
list = []
xyz_dictionary = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3}
list.append(xyz_dictionary)
.... #append all xyz values
data = {'xyz' : list}
json_data = json.dumps(data) # save the data in Json format
json.dump(data, outfile) # or save it directly to a file
```

To read the file

```
json_data=open(file_directory).read()
data = json.loads(json_data)
```

Comment: how would you go about creating a json file with the array of objects as the content so that you can then use pandas to load it into a dataframe? thank u

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the file, append the new data then write it back. Then you can load it into pandas correctly.

```
import json, os
import pandas as pd

filepath = 'jsonfile.json'

class get_file:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path or filename
    def __enter__(self):
        #see if file exists and create if not
        data = {'xyz_data':[]}
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            file = open(path, 'rw')
            json.dump(data, file)
        else:
            #This is just to ensure that the file is valid json
            #if not it replaces the old datafile with a blank json file
            #This is hacky and you will lose all old data!
            file = open(path, 'rw') as file:
            try:
                data = json.load(file)
            except ValueError:
                json.dump(data, file)

        #this line can be deleted, just shows the data after opening
        print(data)
        self.file = file
        return file

    def __exit__(self):
        self.file.close()

def append_data(data, path: str=None):
    """Appends data to the file at the given path, defaults to filepath"""
    path = path or filepath
    with get_data(path) as json_file:
        d = json.load(json_file)
        d = d['xyz_data']
        if isinstance(d, list):
            d.extend(data)
        elif isinstance(d, dict):
            d.append(data)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Must be list or dict")
        json.dump(d, json_file)

def get_dataframe(path):
    path = path or filepath
    with get_data(path) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data['xyz_data'])
    return df
```

This is untested as I'm not at my workstation but hopefully it gets the concept across.
Let me know if there are any errors!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append new data to a Pandas-compatible json, you will face the fact that there is no `mode="a"` as in to_csv. However, we can still easily and memory-efficiently append the dataframe to JSON. Just use `orient='records', lines=True` in `to_json` method.

```py
with open(out_path, "a") as out:
    newdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
    newdf.to_json(out, orient='records', lines=True)
```

Then you can read the whole dataset in the same way.

```py
newdf = pd.read_json(out_path, orient='records', lines=True)
```